# Element has the same name with different types in WSDL

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, wsdl2java

I was given a WSDL and schema files.  I'm using these files to create the stubs in Java.   But I'm getting an error when generating the error (below).   I know what the problem is I just don't know how to fix it.  I understand what the problem is that at times the PayLoadLength is at times string or integer

```
<xs:element name="PayloadLength" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
```

or

```
<xs:element name="PayloadLength" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int"/>
```

schema file (portion of the file where you can see PayloadLength that is either an int or string:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a>-->
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="xxxxxx" xmlns:tns="xxxxxxxxxx" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="ABCBatchResultsAckSubmission" type="tns:ABCBatchResultsAckSubmission"/>

  <xs:element name="ABCBatchResultsAckSubmissionResponse" type="tns:ABCBatchResultsAckSubmissionResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="ABCBatchResultsRetrievalRequest" type="tns:ABCBatchResultsRetrievalRequest"/>

  <xs:element name="ABCBatchResultsRetrievalRequestResponse" type="tns:ABCBatchResultsRetrievalRequestResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="ABCBatchSubmission" type="tns:ABCBatchSubmission"/>

  <xs:element name="ABCBatchSubmissionAckRetrievalRequest" type="tns:ABCBatchSubmissionAckRetrievalRequest"/>

  <xs:element name="ABCBatchSubmissionAckRetrievalRequestResponse" type="tns:ABCBatchSubmissionAckRetrievalRequestResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="ABCBatchSubmissionResponse" type="tns:ABCBatchSubmissionResponse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="ABCBatchSubmissionAckRetrievalRequest">
    <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="PayloadLength" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>

    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ABCBatchSubmissionAckRetrievalRequestResponse">
    <xs:sequence>

    <xs:element name="PayloadLength" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int"/>

    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ABCBatchSubmission">
    <xs:sequence>

      <xs:element name="PayloadLength" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>

    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ABCBatchSubmissionResponse">
    <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="PayloadLength" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int"/>


    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ABCBatchResultsRetrievalRequest">
    <xs:sequence>

      <xs:element name="PayloadLength" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>

    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ABCBatchResultsRetrievalRequestResponse">
    <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="PayloadLength" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int"/>

    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ABCBatchResultsAckSubmission">
    <xs:sequence>

      <xs:element name="PayloadLength" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>

    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ABCBatchResultsAckSubmissionResponse">
    <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="PayloadLength" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int"/>

    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

So I know I need to create an JAXB Binding file to fix issue.   I'm pretty sure this is wrong (below).  But I think I need to target the PayLoadLength and change its name to something else.  **Is that right?**

pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/CORETransactionService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/CORETransactionService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Error:

```
Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java failed: Element PayloadLength has the same name with different types[{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string -- {http://
 www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int]. This will cause a collision in wrapper style as per the spec. (org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java:generate-sources:generate-sources) 
 org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java failed: Element PayloadLength has the same name with different types[{http://
 www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string -- {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int]. This will cause a collision in wrapper style as per the spec. at 
 org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:
 112) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115) at 
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:
 112) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177) 
 at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99) 
 at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86) at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735) at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:
 206) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301) at 
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383) at 
 org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:142) at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:232) at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56) 
 Caused by: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Element PayloadLength has the same name with different types[{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string -- {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int]. This 
 will cause a collision in wrapper style as per the spec. at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.validate(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:735) at 
 org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:276) at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164) at 
 org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412) at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105) at 
 org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113) at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86) at 
 org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:414) at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:279) at 
 org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:511) at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134) ... 31 more
```

Comment: I think we're missing something here. Is this *really* your schema? If `Request` and `Response` are completely separate types (as per your code) then elements with the same name and different types should not be a problem at all. Do they maybe have a super-type they both extend?

Comment: Sorry I changed the names for Response and Request.  I don't see a super type that they both extend.

Comment: The thing is, the schema snippet you've posted will most probably not produce the problem you're reporting. So please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Complete and verifiable. I'll vote to close until then.

Comment: @lexicore I posted the schema file.  I just left the PayLoadLength element there in each call.  What else do you need the wsdl file also?

Comment: I could compile your schema with `xjc` without any problems. I think it would make sense to make a MCVE ready-to-build project and share it via GitHub. I will take a look then.

Comment: Is is possible I can email you instead?

Comment: No, sorry. I can support you pro bono if other SO users will be able to learn from it. This implies making your code public.

Comment: Okay.  I just don't want to share the full WSDL and schema file since its from the client.  So I would need to change it a bit but so it still produces the error I'm seeing.  Let me see how I can do that.  Thanks.

Comment: Right, it does not have to be exactly *the* files in your production project, just something which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169616/discussion-between-mindgame-and-lexicore).

Comment: @lexicore.  Would you have any ideas on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121221/cxf-set-soap-version-to-1-2

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much CXF experience.

Comment: No worries.  Just thought I ask.

Comment: @lexicore: So as you know i have the generate stubs.  So after that. What would you use to consume the web services?  Other then CXF.

Comment: I would take CXF, sorry I don't have any other suggestion at the moment.

Comment: Oh okay.  I just thought maybe there was another way to consume it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite an extensive analysis, the problem appeared to be in the so-called "wrapper style". To quote [WSDL To Java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html):

> Note: The meaning of "wrapper-style" and "non-wrapper style" as defined in the JAX-WS 2.1 specification can be counterintuitive. Wrapper-style indicates that each data element within the request message gets its own Java parameter, while non-wrapper style means that a single Java object containing all the data elements serves as the lone parameter to the web service method call.

So basically the problem is that if you have some sub-elements in the request and the response types which have the same name, they will essentially map to one parameter. And if they have different types, this causes a collision and CXF rejects them.

One way to resolve this is to disable wrapper style. You can do this with a `binding.xml` file like:

```
<jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Include it in the configuration of the `cxf-codegen-plugin`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/My.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/My.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                <bindingFiles>
                                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                                </bindingFiles>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

There is also *probably* another way, at least the error message, at least the error message suggests that it should be possible to "use a JAXWS/JAXB binding customization to rename the parameter". Unfortunately I could not figure out the right syntax of bindings for this.